Adding colorbar to imshow in matplotlib makes plot stick to the right
When i added a colorbar to an imshow plot within pyside6 application, the whole plot sticks to the right (see picture).
image of matrix that stick to the right
When there is no colorbar, the plot is centered as it should be.
The source code of the PySide6 component is:
class Matrix(MplCanvas):
    def __init__(self, size: tuple[int, int]) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        set_axis_color(self.ax, style.Style.TextColor.NORMAL.value)

        self.img = self.ax.imshow(np.zeros(size),
                                  origin='lower',
                                  interpolation='nearest',
                                  norm=mpl_colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=10))
        self.colorbar = self.figure.colorbar(self.img, ax=self.ax)
        self.colorbar.ax.tick_params(
            which='both',
            color=style.Style.TextColor.NORMAL.value,
            labelcolor=style.Style.TextColor.NORMAL.value)
        for spine in self.colorbar.ax.spines.values():
            spine.set_edgecolor(style.Style.TextColor.NORMAL.value)

        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.canvas.flush_events()

I tried using 'auto' aspect on axis, which again centers the plot, but I need the resulting plot to be kept as a square. Also tried to fiddle with colorbar arguments but could not find a correct combintaion that would align the plot correctly.

See github issue 5463. The suggested solution is to use fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='compressed'). It's unclear whether that works for you, as you didn't provide fully reproducible code.

Thanks a lot,  layout='compressed' did the trick! I will be more specific next time. ^^
